# How do I pass arguments from tkinter function to external module?

Tags: python, tkinter, argparse

I would like to call an external module (python script) from a `tkinter` button. My external module `text_parser.py` requires a single argument and looks like this:

```py
import argparse


def main(filename):

    # Parse arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    # Parse text
```

My button code looks like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

# Import text parser script
from text_parser import *


def browse_files():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()


def parse_text():
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main(filename)


# Create window
window = Tk()

# Define Select TXT button
select_TXT_button = Button(window, text='Select TXT', command=browse_files)
select_TXT_button.pack()

# Define Parse TXT button
parse_TXT_button = Button(window, text='Parse TXT', command=parse_text)
parse_TXT_button.pack()

# Enter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

When running the button code `gui.py`, the `Select TXT` button works without error. However, subsequently clicking the `Parse TXT` button results in the following error:

```
usage: gui.py [-h] filename
gui.py: error: the following arguments are required: filename

Process finished with exit code 2
```

It appears that `filename` is (unexpectedly) not passing to the `text_parser` module. How can I pass arguments to external modules from `tkinter` functions?

Comment: @Thingamabobs unfortunately, no. Using the `lambda` approach still results in the same argument error.

Comment: My bad, prejudged your question by appearance and retracted my vote. On first glance I can't see why your code isn't working. Is it your actual code or did you alter something like put code out of a class ?

Comment: @Thingamabobs no worries. This is my actual code (no custom classes).

Comment: Since I don't use `argparse` myself, I'm not sure, but it seems you should do this: `args = parser.parse_args(['filename', filename])`, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args)

Comment: Is the filename variable assigned a value or is it null?

Comment: Why do you use `argparse` inside `main()`? It is not necessary.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial for argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html#argparse-tutorial), however it seems not be useful in your case, since you don't do a command line interface, you do a graphical user interface. It makes little to no sense to use that in this context, rather validate the input and show a `errormessage` to the user. However, since `filedialog` grantees to return a `string` it also makes little to no sense to do that.

Comment: @IslandPatrol You can first check if the filename variable is assigned a value and then pass it to the main function.

Comment: @Dinux `filename` is assigned a value (a string representing the path of the file). Calling `print(filename)` in `browse_files()` returns the expected path string.

Comment: @acw1668 moving `argparse` out of `main()` results in the `tkinter` GUI failing to launch completely. I get the same missing argument error.

Comment: What I said is that `argparse` is not necessary, not moving it out of the function.

Comment: @acw1668 although this resolves the problem in this simplified case, `argparse` is necessary because `text_parser.py` can also be run separately / independently.

Comment: Then you need to put the code related to `argparse` inside `if __name__ == "__main__":` in the main block (outside `main()`). Note also that such if block is not necessary inside `parse_text()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments can be passed by making changes to both `text_parser.py` and the button code `gui.py`:

`text_parser.py`: move `argparse` out of `main()` as @acw1668 suggested:

```py
def main(filename):
    print(f'Parsing: {filename}')
    # Parse text


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import argparse

    # Parse filename from arguments
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('filename', type=str)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    filename = vars(args)['filename']

    main(filename)
```

`gui.py`: similarly, remove `if __name__ == '__main__':`:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

# Import text parser script
from text_parser import *


def browse_files():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()


def parse_text():
    main(filename)


# Create window
window = Tk()

# Define Select TXT button
select_TXT_button = Button(window, text='Select TXT', command=browse_files)
select_TXT_button.pack()

# Define Parse TXT button
parse_TXT_button = Button(window, text='Parse TXT', command=parse_text)
parse_TXT_button.pack()

# Enter event loop
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Using the ‘global’ keyword is not good practice. You can put the ‘global filename’ variable outside the ‘browse_files’ function.

Comment: @Dinux that doesn't work, unfortunately. Moving `global filename` out of `browse_files()` results in: `NameError: name 'filename' is not defined` in `parse_text()`.

Comment: Oh, ok. I am not sure why you get a NameError, because if a variable is outside a function then the variable becomes global by default